# i'm adding camera for my scene to render but around my object unlimited camera is appearing and also i'm working on geometry nodes

Tags: camera, geometry-nodes

[image]

blender2.93.1 camera issue in viewport

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have chosen the camera as Point instance object. Either choose another object or just remove the camera as point instance object.

[image]

Comment: if my solution doesn't help you, please show us your node tree